# Any library to read mdict *.MDX files in android?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-studio, dictionary

I have a `.mdx file` that infact is a dictionary database (some android apps like bluedict can read its data).
I have used Daemon.tools but it could not open it.
I was looking for any library or sources which helps me to read MDX dictionary files in Java, I have found some resources already such as [KnIfER/mdict-java](https://github.com/KnIfER/mdict-java) but it does not work in Android Studio (it has errors on `accumulation_blockId_tree.xxing(new myCpr(position,1)).getKey().value` line and it is `connot resolve symbol 'value'`). Does any one knows a good source about these files and possible libraries which could be used for it?.

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually this is my java project.
the error mentioned is just a problem of jdk version. you can add <> parentheses after myCpr and convert return of xxing to type `myCpr<Integer,Integer>`  .
But now, I have very much reduced usage of rbtree and use more binary list searching.have a look there.